# Delete field from JSON file in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file

I want to delete a field from a JSON file in node. Suppose my file looks like this

```
{
    'name': John Doe,
    'nickname': Johnny
}
```

and if I say `delete('nickname');` I want it to look like this.

```
{
    'name': John Doe
}
```

How should I go about doing this? Also is there a way to check how many elements are left in the file? And if so how could I delete the whole file if it is empty?

***update:*** this is the code I'm debugging

```
var data = require(pathToFile);
            var element = data[deleteKey];
            delete element;
            fs.writeFileSync(pathToFile, JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), 'utf8');
            res.end(deleteKey + ' was deleted');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Comment: `var element = data[deleteKey]; delete element;` should be `delete data[deleteKey];`

Comment: yes this was just for debugging purposes. but neither way works haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check how many elements are left in the JSON file, you can use this:

```
Object.keys(jsonArray).length;
```

To delete an element however:

```
var json = 
{
'name': John Doe,
'nickname': Johnny
}
var key = "name";
delete json[key];
```

As for deleting a file, you can use ajax and call a server-side file to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

You can just delete it...

```
var myObj = { 'name': 'John Doe', 'nickname': 'Johnny'};
delete myObj.nickname;
```

**OR**

```
var myObj = { 'name': 'John Doe', 'nickname': 'Johnny' };
delete myObj["nickname"];
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{name: "John Doe"}
```

Comment: its a file! and i've tried "myObj=require('myjsonfile.json')" and then "delete myObj[key]" and it has not worked

Comment: so read the content of the file into a variable and then you can use the above code (you should also update your question to reflect the specific code you're trying to troubleshoot.)

Comment: is that not what I'm doing in the above comment? It did not work

Comment: No. You need to provide the exact code reflecting the problem you're trying to solve. The above code gives me an assumption that you already have a variable within your code that holds the json string. if this is the case, the above code should work.

Comment: the file is not updating with the proper delete